# Node & Elastic Beanstalk: Set environment NODE_ENV=prod

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to execute the following command for production environment:

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

I tried passing it as a command under Configueration:

[image]

I get the following error in the logs:

```
sh: NODE_ENV=prod node app.js: command not found
```

I also tried:

```
NODE_ENV=prod  // 
error: sh: NODE_ENV=prod: command not found


NODE_ENV=prod app.js  // 
error: sh: NODE_ENV=prod app.js: command not found
```

What's the best way to execute the following command when launching the app on ELB:

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to set the node command manually. Elastic Beanstalk attempts to start `app.js`, then `server.js`, and then `npm start` in that order. You can set the value of `NODE_ENV` in the "Environment Properties" section under "Configuration".

[image]

Comment: I have done this, but it doesn't work. It is overwritten to "production"

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you can manually add them by going to Configuration -> Software -> Environment properties.

A second way to do this is to add a `.ebextensions/environment.config` file.

1. Add the directory `.ebextensions` at the root of your project.
2. Create the file `environment.config` within `.ebextensions`.
3. Add your environment configurations.

Example of `environment.config`:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: production
```

Comment: In my opinion it's better to keep track of such things in config files as you point out. The case is technically already won by the overwhelming support for configuration +  infrastructure as code with cloudformation and terraform etc.

Comment: I have done this, but it doesn't work. It is overwritten to "production"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "Environment Properties" Not the node command.

[image]

```
Key: NODE_ENV
Value: production
```

Comment: I have done this, but it doesn't work. It is overwritten to "production"

Answer (score 0):

I would just set `NODE_ENV` in Environment Properties under the same configuration area.  You can also set this in your `.ebextensions` config.

Comment: I have done this, but it doesn't work. It is overwritten to "production"

Comment: @snehanshu.js Rather that commenting on everyone's answers, you should post a new question, along with details.